# Java Web App, SQL, архитектура

Tags: sql, база-данных

Добрый день,
возникла следующая диллема. Есть некие данные которые хранятся в БД, на основе этих данных производятся некоторые расчёты в последующем для представления пользователю. Однако эти же данные, только в несколько ином виде будут нужны на других страницах, просто для вывода и для построения графиков. Собстевнное как лучше поступить, получать данные от пользователя на их осонве делать расчет и заносить все это в базу (что бы в будущем просто брать готовые данные из базы) или по запросу(при переходе на конкретную страницу) брать из базы первоначальные данные делать все расчёты и выводить на веб-представление??
Спасибо.

Comment: Почитайте статейки на тему OLAP. Даже если и не совсем то, что надо, в любом случае покажет и обоснует подход к обработке данных и хранению результатов этой обработки.

Comment: Обе парадигмы активно применяются. В SQL-мире больше принят расчет при запросе (*pull-on-demand*), второй подход более сложен (требуется постоянно следить за предотвращением утечки целостности данных), но позволяет рассчитать данные всего один раз, а потом подтягивать уже готовый ответ (*push-on-change*), что, при правильной архитектуре, позволяет не задумываться об оптимизации вообще.

Comment: @Etki не уверен что точно уловил суть вашего ответа. Меня очень смущает описаный мною первый вариант, получается что я в базе при таком раскладе буду хранить как оригинальные данные, так и рассчитанные на их осонове (т.е. по сути можно сказать дублирующие). Насколько это правильно при таком подходе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько понимаю, вы сомневаетесь в "легальности" каждого двух методов: записывать только "сырые" данные и обрабатывать их по необходимости, и записывать данные сразу в тех вариациях, которые могут понадобиться. Забегая вперед, можно сразу сказать, что оба вполне легальны и используются во многих и многих приложениях, и вы можете выбрать любой из них.

Самым легким решением является "записывать сырые данные и получать необходимые в момент запроса", для этой модели часто применяется название **pull-on-demand** - "вытащить по запросу". При использовании SQL эта модель применяется практически по умолчанию - принято хранить нормализованные, недублирующиеся данные, используя join-конструкции для того, чтобы собрать результирующую картину. Этот подход является живой классикой, и, в данном случае, я бы рекомендовал придерживаться его, пока не появится уверенность в том, что сможете реализовать в проекте второй.

Плюсы:

- Данные не дублируются, и, в случае необходимости дополнительной работы с ними, точно известно, что они находятся в одном месте
- Инфраструктура легко поддерживается: все методы записи-поиска-модификации-удаления абсолютно одинаковы
- Обновление данных происходит синхронно во всех местах

Минусы:

- Расчет конечных данных производится каждый раз
- При необходимости построения сложных данных можно просто подвесить сервер

Вторая модель, именуемая **push-on-change**, гораздо сложнее в имплементации, но имеет ряд неоспоримых плюсов. Эта модель подразумевает, что данные сохраняются в подготовленных для запросов виде, а сами запросы сводятся к простому `SELECT ... FROM xxx_prepared_for_yyy_query WHERE ... LIMIT offset, size`.

Плюсы:

- Однократное вычисление данных
- Значительное облегчение работы для базы данных и практически гарантированное выполнение выборки в пределах 50мс даже на очень больших объемах данных (на хороших хранилищах - до 10мс)
- Автоматический отказ от джойнов, который позволяет применять горизонтально масштабируемые хранилища

Все вышеперечисленные плюсы автоматом требуются в highload-приложениях, поэтому там, как правило, используется именно этот подход.

Минусы:

- Гораздо более высокая стоимость разработки (программист должен сам вручную создавать архитектуру для каждой сущности, которая будет обновлять связанные таблицы с подготовленными данными)
- Гораздо более высокая вероятность бага
- Гораздо сложнее добавлять новые форматы выгрузки данных
- Данные могут быть "размазаны" по нескольким таблицам

Повторюсь, что оба подхода применяются не первый день, и оба абсолютно легальны. В большинстве случаев требуется находить компромисс (не будете же вы создавать таблицу под каждую поисковую выборку, равно как и подсчитывать количество комментариев к каждой новости на лету?), поэтому обычно в чистом виде они не применяются, однако все равно на 90% должен соблюдаться тот или иной подход, чтобы разработка не превратилась в ад. От себя могу порекомендовать на некоторое время остаться с первым подходом - высчитыванием данных по запросу - до тех пор, пока не будет времени поэксперементировать со вторым.